# DeepLinkDispatch with different modules (libraries)

Tags: android, android-deep-link, android-module, android-flavors, buildconfig

I'm trying to add [DeepLinkDispatch](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch) library (by airbnb) in my project in order to handle deeplinks. The project has different modules and some links needs to be handled by `Activity`'s in this modules.

As I have different flavors I would like to define the url of deeplinks with BuildConfig in `build.gradle`, to be able to do something like this:

```
@DeepLink("${BuildConfig. WEB_BASE_URL}/deepLink/{id}", "${BuildConfig. WEB_BASE_URL}/anotherDeepLink")
class ModuleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   // This class is in :module, so it has no access to BuildConfig main :app module
}
```

But unfortunately I don't have access to BuildConfig from modules

I also tried to reproduce the flavors in Modules like this:

```
//module build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

apply from: rootProject.file("buildscripts/android-defaults.gradle")

import dependencies.deps

android {
    defaultPublishConfig "alphaRelease"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {

    }
    flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        alpha {
            buildConfigField "String", "WEB_BASE_URL", "\"https://staging.example.com\""
            dimension "env"
        }
        production {
            buildConfigField "String", "WEB_BASE_URL", "\"https://example.com\""
            dimension "env"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    //...
}
```

but it seems this is not possible, I'm getting this error:

`Product Flavor 'alpha' contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.`

Is there any way to solve this without hardcoding the whole url in the `@DeepLink` annotation?

EDIT: this is the main app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//**

android {
    defaultConfig {
        //**
    }
    
    productFlavors {
        alpha {
            applicationIdSuffix '.alpha'
        }
        production {
            applicationIdSuffix '.prod'
        }
    }
    //**
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':module')
    //**
}
```

Comment: Can you also add gradle for other modules like app module?

Comment: ModuleActivity class is in which module? and have you implemented the library module in that module?

Comment: Thanks @NareshNK for your interest. I edited the question to add app module gradle. ModuleActivity is in the library (:module) that's the problem, from this library I don't have access to main app BuildConfig and, as explained, I'm not able to create buildConfigField's in the library (:module)

Comment: I was unable to figure out the issue with your code. I have created a repo on GitHub explaining how to use multi module buildConfigField variable share, that might help you achive your goal. Url : https://github.com/Noddy20/Multi-Module-Gradle-Config

Comment: thanks @NareshNK. I tried your test project and it's working. I don't see any difference, so I don't know what's happening in my side. I will try to start a new project from scratch to see what's happening.